# Using field axioms to prove the next

Tags: calculus, real-numbers, axioms

how can it be proved using field axioms that

$\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{100}}=\frac{\sqrt[3]{10}}{10}$

I have the next sketch proof:

First I applied the definition of quotient. Then I used that $1=(\sqrt[3]{100^2})(\sqrt[3]{100^2})^{-1}$. And then use commutativity together with $(a\cdot b)^{-1}=a^{-1}\cdot b^{-1}$

But how do I justify that $\sqrt[3]{100^2}\sqrt[3]{100}=100$?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: $\sqrt[3]{a} \sqrt[3]{b} = \sqrt[3]{ab}$. The proof of this, of course, depends on your definition of $\sqrt[3]{\cdot}$.

Comment: One way of proving it is to recognize that in real analysis, $~a = b \iff a^3 = b^3.~$  This is because the function $~f(x) = x^3~$ is a strictly increasing function.  Then, taking your last result, and cubing both sides, proving your assertion reduces to trying to prove that $~(100)^2 \times (100) = (100)^3,~$ which is **true, by definition**.